# APPEND_SLASH doesn't work for me with Django 4

Tags: python, django

Django version 4.0.2

###### settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
APPEND_SLASH = True
```

###### project's urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('poolapp.urls')),
]
```

###### app's urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', index, name="index"),
]
```

With the same configuration, If I visit `127.0.0.1/index` , Django 3.x redirects me to `127.0.0.1/index/` .

Django `4.0.2` returns `404`.

Did something change with `Django 4.x`?

Comment: It doesn't seem that this logic got significant changes in django 4.x version. APPEND_SLASH is used only in CommonMiddleware and you can directly debug this behavior there. Do you have any other custom middlewares?

Comment: No, it's a fresh project.